# Does php date function automatically factor in leap year

Tags: php, date

So I'm just making a basic calendar for each month, just to play with the date function in PHP. I use something very simple code that I was thinking of throwing into a loop and populate some cells in a table:

```
public function getDayDate(){
    $month = "January";
    $day="1";
    $year="2014";
    $theW = "$month $day $year";
            //First day of the week on a month
    echo date("D", strtotime($theW));
            //# of days in a month
    echo date("t", strtotime($theW));
}
```

But it came to my mind about leap year and all other kinds of calendar events that may effect the number of days in a month. And i was wondering if this basic setup automatically factors these things in with the data here. Cause I figured I can have start on a particular cell like Wednesday and loop it 28-31 times to add the day to each cell until it completes.

Is this wrong? I tried searching for about a day, and most of the questions are more specific for finding the leap year and/or event, instead of it automatically just giving the end result, which is the number of days in the month and what day of the week it starts on.

I appreciate your help!

Comment: I suggest to use php DateTime object, I think date() function is deprecated.

Comment: `date` knows about leap years, yes. I'd prefer a `DateTime`, `DateInterval` & `DatePeriod` combo for creating calendars, but that is just a personal preference.

Comment: And `date` is NOT deprecated (and most likely never will, there's no reason), but `DateTime` has a LOT of advantages.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, PHP's [`DateTime`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class does.  You can even check if it is a leap year with the `L` formatter.

```
$date = date_create();
$isLeapYear = $date->format('L');
var_dump($isLeapYear);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily test it. Calculate the diff between Feb 27th and March 2nd for example in a leap year and in a non leap year and you will see that they are different.

I recommend you use DateTime::createFromFormat for transforming your string into a date.